# excel min value different than 0 such that the next value is 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've the following matrix, and I need to get the hours of the minimum and maximum values from each block of ones.

[image: See my example:]

In my first attempt, I've obtained the first 1 and the last one (8:30 and 17:00) using the minifs and maxifs formula.

Since I couldn't obtain 11:00 and 12:30, I changed my approach. I've created a help matrix with 48 columns that gives 0,1,2,3 or 4 in the positions that I want. See it:

[image: help matrix]

However, doing this help matrix increases the file size a lot. I wish that I could get the middle hours by using just a formula. I don't want to use the help matrix.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe what you need these hours for? Any further calculation need to be done with those? If so, you might be able to do it in one go.

Comment: Hi! My goal is just to summarize the information in 4 columns. start hour of 1st block, end hour of 1st block, start hour of 2nd block and end hour of 2nd block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the first cell and drag across and down:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN($B2:$AV2)/(($A2:$AU2=--(ISEVEN(COLUMN(A1))))*($B2:$AV2=--(ISODD(COLUMN(A1))))),INT((COLUMN(A1)-1)/2)+1)-ISEVEN(COLUMN(A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: What if someone starts a first shift at 00:30? I'm also puzzling =). I guess a normal `INDEX` & `MATCH` would do and your formula for the other three.

Comment: @JvdV if that were a possiblity I would move every thing over a column and leave column A blank, making the adjustment to the formula to start on column A to the new AW

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's also a possibility. Looking at the data again I think your formula does the trick though since the first zero appears at `7:30` and the last one at `22:00` =)

Comment: Actually it does not matter if there are any `0` in the data.  The formula sees blank as `0`

Comment: @ScottCraner, your formula works really well! Thanks! If I need to add x rows and y columns and than put the formula right after 0:30, what should I change? I've tried to add a new column 'A', and the formula crashed :/

Comment: I am not getting your request, one should show their setup so the answer can be correct.

Comment: I mean that instead of 00:30 is in the cell A1, if is in the cell D2 what should I change in the formula.

Comment: Change all the absolute($) references accordingly, leaving the other references(A1) the same.  `=INDEX($2:$2,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN($E3:$AY3)/(($D3:$AX3=--(ISEVEN(COLUMN(A1))))*($E3:$AY3=--(ISODD(COLUMN(A1))))),INT((COLUMN(A1)-1)/2)+1)-ISEVEN(COLUMN(A1)))`